# How do I accept input from arrow keys, or accept directional input?

Tags: python, text-editor

This may be an xy problem, but I'm trying to to build a kernel based text editor, similar to `vim` or `nano`, and I know how to use the escape chars to clear the screen, then reprint, I can have it accept characters, but I'm not sure how to get it to accept arrow inputs for navigation. I thought there were ASCII values for them, but apparently not. Is there a way to use the arrows, or do I have to make a navigation mode and insert mode like `vim`?

I've also briefly played with `curses`, but that was prohibitive because, as I understood, a whole new window had to be opened for it and this is not compatible with the vision of a single terminal window that I had.

Please note that `curses` does not work because it cleares the window, which I don't want.

Comment: I think yo may be misunderstanding the `curses` meaning of window. Its a window as printed *in* the terminal screen. So if you had a terminal open, and ran your `curses` program it would be in the same terminal, much like VIm.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I think I may have. I'm going over the functions of curses, and am trying it in the python test thingy, and it's not opening new windows like I saw before. Maybe I'll give 'curses' another chance.

Comment: @JFA Do you mean the IDLE? The IDLE is **not** a terminal, hence when you try to run something with `curses` it has to open a terminal to make it work. But if you already have a terminal open then it'll use that.

Comment: Right, IDLE. I only use IDLE to test pieces of code before implementing them in my code, or to try new libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wound up using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user), and modifying the `__init__` statement so that it accepted up to 3 characters in a list.

```
import sys

class _Getch:
   """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the
screen."""
   def __init__(self):
      self.impl = _GetchUnix()

   def __call__(self):# return self.impl()
      charlist = []
      counter = 0
      for i in range(3):
         try:charlist.append(self.impl())
         except:pass
         if charlist[i] not in [chr(27),chr(91)]:#TODO sort out escape vs arrow duh use len()
            break
         if len(charlist) > 1:
            if charlist == [chr(27),chr(27)]:
               break
      if len(charlist) == 3:
         if charlist[2] == 'a'
            return 'u-arr'
         if charlist[2] == 'b'
            return 'd-arr'
         if charlist[2] == 'c'
            return 'r-arr'
         if charlist[2] == 'd'
            return 'l-arr'
      if len(charlist == 2):
         if charlist == [chr(27),chr(27)]
            return chr(27)
      if len(charlist == 1)
         return charlist[0]
      return ''

class _GetchUnix:
   def __init__(self):
      import tty, sys

   def __call__(self):
      import sys, tty, termios
      fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
      old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
      try:
         tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
         ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
      finally:
         termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
      return ch
```

This allowed me to get arrow keys as well as all other characters and escape sequences from the keyboard for the editor. It made the "Getch" class not strictly a `get char` clone because it returns a string, but it wound up being much more useful.

Answer (score 10):

`curses` is **exactly** what you want. In fact I believe vim implements its interface with curses.

Try to put the following code into a file called `test_curses.py`:

```
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()
screen.addstr("Hello World!!!")
screen.refresh()
screen.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

Now open a *terminal* (not IDLE! a real terminal!) and run it via:

```
python test_curses.py
```

You should see that *the terminal* was cleared and an `Hello World!!!` writing appeared. Press any key and the program will stop, restoring the old terminal contents.

Note that the `curses` library isn't as easy and "user-friendly" as you may be accustomed to. I suggest reading the [tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) (unfortunately for the C language, but the python interface is mostly the same)

Comment: Yea I was playing with curses last night, and it was not unlike playing with fire, but I think it is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JFA There *is* a reason why the library is called `curses`: you generally curse the entire world when using it! It doesn't have a user-friendly API. Also it was written long time ago, when terminals and computer graphics was slow, hence a lot of the API is written with optimization in mind, which is awesome when you need that, but makes everything more complicated in the common case.

Comment: Is there a way to create a safe file to restore my terminal for `curses`? I keep winding up with a terminal that doesn't echo or print. Also, does `curses` have to clear the screen, or can it work in a small section after the input.

Comment: @JFA You should remember to call `curses.endwin()`. If you abort the application (e.g. with `Ctrl+C`) you probably end up in that situations. To avoid that you can either catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, call `curses.endwin()` and then re-raise the exception, or add a [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook). AFAIK `curses` works only on the whole terminal.

Comment: `curses`... If that's the case, it's going to do the things that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Is there a way to copy everything in the terminal so far into curses? Otherwise I think I'm going to have to use an insert and navigation mode, which is becoming more and more friendly the more I think about `curses`.

Answer (score 4):

I know that I'm late to the party, but I really liked [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) package mentioned by [@elbaschid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1258219/elbaschid). I don't know why he wasn't upvoted - maybe because his example doesn't show how to handle specifically cursor keys.

Here is my $0.02 on that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import click

printable = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

while True:
    click.echo('Continue? [yn] ', nl=False)
    c = click.getchar()
    click.echo()
    if c == 'y':
        click.echo('We will go on')
    elif c == 'n':
        click.echo('Abort!')
        break
    elif c == '\x1b[D':
        click.echo('Left arrow <-')
    elif c == '\x1b[C':
        click.echo('Right arrow ->')
    else:
        click.echo('Invalid input :(')
        click.echo('You pressed: "' + ''.join([ '\\'+hex(ord(i))[1:] if i not in printable else i for i in c ]) +'"' )
```

This handles cursor keys and as a bonus prints py-string representation of any keyboard shortcut it doesn't yet recognize. For example Ctrl-s is `"\x13"`. You can later use it inside another

```
elif c == ??
```

I've tried to add edit to [@elbaschid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1258219/elbaschid) answer but it was rejected ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Please give him credit if you also like my answer

Awesome library for quick command-line prototyping.

Answer (score 3):

The Python package [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) used for building commandline clients also comes with an implementation that allows you to get the key press events:

```
import click

key = click.getchar()
```

It returns the key representation as Unicode character and "things like arrow keys will show up in the platform’s native escape format.".

This is the example taken straight from the [click documentation on `getchar`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/utils/#getting-characters-from-terminal):

```
import click

click.echo('Continue? [yn] ', nl=False)
c = click.getchar()
click.echo()
if c == 'y':
    click.echo('We will go on')
elif c == 'n':
    click.echo('Abort!')
else:
    click.echo('Invalid input :(')
```

Comment: This actually very decent package and very decent answer - except that it lacks handling arrow keys - I've let myself fix in this minor problem

Answer (score 2):

**To Perform  desired Action on Arrow key or Any other key as it pressed**

```
# key_event_handler.py

import sys
import select
import pty
import os
import time
import fcntl
import tty
import termios
def __select( iwtd, owtd, ewtd, timeout=None):

   '''This is a wrapper around select.select() that ignores signals. If
   select.select raises a select.error exception and errno is an EINTR
   error then it is ignored. Mainly this is used to ignore sigwinch
   (terminal resize). '''

   # if select() is interrupted by a signal (errno==EINTR) then
   # we loop back and enter the select() again.
   if timeout is not None:
       end_time = time.time() + timeout
   while True:
       try:
           return select.select(iwtd, owtd, ewtd, timeout)
       except select.error:
           err = sys.exc_info()[1]
           if err.args[0] == errno.EINTR:
               # if we loop back we have to subtract the
               # amount of time we already waited.
               if timeout is not None:
                   timeout = end_time - time.time()
                   if timeout < 0:
                       return([], [], [])
           else:
               # something else caused the select.error, so
               # this actually is an exception.
               raise

STDIN_FILENO=pty.STDIN_FILENO
STDOUT_FILENO=pty.STDOUT_FILENO
string_type=bytes
sys.stdout.write(string_type())
sys.stdout.flush()
buffer = string_type()
mode = tty.tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO)
tty.setraw(STDIN_FILENO)
try:
    while True:
        r, w, e = __select([STDIN_FILENO], [], [],timeout=1)
        if STDIN_FILENO in r:
            #It accepts all keys from keyboard 
            data=os.read(STDIN_FILENO, 1)
            #Bellow line returns ASCII value of a charector
            ascii_value=ord(data[0])
            ##########################################################################
            ##                      Your code goes here                             ## 
            ##                                                                      ##
            # Do some action here by matching the ASCII value                        #
            # you can handle your program by making use of special keys like         #
            # Backspace, Ctrl, Ctrl+A,Ctrl+B, Ctrl+C, ...Ctrl+Z, Esc,F1, ...,F12 ....#
            # Tab,Enter,Arrow keys,Alphabetic and Numeric keys are also supported    #  
            ##########################################################################
            #                                                                        #
            #To Print use bellow line rather than print or sys.stdout.write(data)    #
            #os.write(STDOUT_FILENO,data)                                            #
            ##                                                                       #
            ##########################################################################


finally:
    tty.tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, tty.TCSAFLUSH, mode)
```

> Then open terminal and run `key_event_handler.py`

---

> This program is mainly to capture key pressed and get ascii of key pressed, This program can also be used for non-Blocking I/O in multy threaded aplications