# Selenium wait for keypress, python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want selenium to open page and wait for keypress, based on key pressed script should  do different actions. It seems there is no Expected Conditions for this case, how can I write my own?

Here is pseudo code:

```
driver.get('http://google.com')
# wait for keypress
# if keypress == ARROW_RIGHT:
#     print "ARROW_RIGHT"
# elif keypress == ARROW_LEFT:
#     print "ARROW_LEFT"
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a python method to check for a key press input. There are different ways to do this depending on if you are using a GUI support library or not. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25307052/2526441) answer, which covers multiple ways on how to work with key presses.

After you detected a key press you can continue performing your task in Selenium.

Comment: This seems like the right answer to accept. I don't claim to have a full overview of seleniums API, but bear in mind that it is an automatic testing library, and that manual inputs are probably out of scope.