# How to use click.getchar() to identify "Enter Key" (python)

Tags: python

I'm making a Python script and wanted to let the user use the Arrow Keys to navigate through the screens.

I found this answer from @yatsa, that really worked for the Arrows:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46449300/11903801

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import click

printable = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

while True:
    click.echo('Continue? [yn] ', nl=False)
    c = click.getchar()
    click.echo()
    if c == 'y':
        click.echo('We will go on')
    elif c == 'n':
        click.echo('Abort!')
        break
    elif c == '\x1b[D':
        click.echo('Left arrow <-')
    elif c == '\x1b[C':
        click.echo('Right arrow ->')
    else:
        click.echo('Invalid input :(')
        click.echo('You pressed: "' + ''.join([ '\\'+hex(ord(i))[1:] if i not in printable else i for i in c ]) +'"' )
```

This example is supposed to identify if it was pressed left-key or right-keys and it also prints the "py-string representation" of any other keyboard key pressed.

Said that, **I had to change the code** to make it work for me...
When I ran the code above it didn't identify the Left and Right arrows.
Instead it printed to me:

`You pressed "\xe0K"` (for left arrow)

and

`You pressed "\xe0M"` (for right arrow)

What did I do?
Replace that values in elifs with this the console printed to me, and **IT WORKED!**

Ok, GOOD, so next I wanted to identify the "Enter Key", so I ran the script, press Enter, and it printed to me: `You pressed "\xd"`

So, what did I do?
Created a new conditional using this string the console printed to me.

**BUT...**

```
    elif c == '\xd':
             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: truncated \xXX escape

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So, I don't know what's the problem, I tried to search the web but didn't found anything that explains it to me.

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: If you really want a text-mode UI, do *NOT* rely on ASCII cursor control characters.  Use a [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses) library: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks, now I'm using tkinter. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using (or referring to) the [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) library. The benefit here is that you'll be able to comply with Windows and Linux (OSX seems to be experimental in this library)

To answer your question specifically, it seems like you should be using [0x0d](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/_winkeyboard.py#L175) for Enter

Edit: Add link to Enter key

Comment: Thanks, now I'm using tkinter for the UI! :)